# OTA push sketch to NodeMCU

Tags: wifi, nodemcu

Similar questions regarding Arduinos mention the existence of tools that would enable the pushing of sketch updates to NodeMCU via WiFi / OTA (Over The Air).

Does this proceed?  If so, please indicate the proper tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arduino IDE supports upload to a network port. Network ports are detected with mDns and made available in Tools>Port menu.

The ArduinoOTA library bundled with the esp8266 Arduino boards package supports upload from IDE with 'network port' over WiFi. See the example of the ArduinoOTA library available in Examples menu in IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there exist methods to update codes through OTA in Wifi-modules/NodeMCU. You will first need to allot an IP address to your device which will later be used as a port to carry out OTA transmission. Look out to this tutorial-https://circuitdigest.com/microcontroller-projects/esp8266-ota-update-programming-using-arduino-ide